# C# Ceasar cipher problem with negative numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

So basically the code works fine for some input, but I want **input** "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and then as a position "-3" , the expected output should be "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw", can anyone help ?

```
            Console.WriteLine("Type a string to encrypt:");
            string UserString = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            Console.Write("Type in the position:");
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("\n");


            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Data");

            string cipherText = Encipher(UserString, key);
            Console.WriteLine(cipherText);
            Console.Write("\n");

            char cipher(char ch, int key)
            {
                if (!char.IsLetter(ch))
                {

                    return ch;
                }

                char d = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
                return (char)((((ch + key) - d) % 26) + d);

            }

            string Encipher(string input, int key)
            {
                string output = string.Empty;

                foreach (char ch in input)
                    output += cipher(ch, key);

                return output;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any *abitrary* number you should use a bit *elaborated remainder*:

```
 result = (source % mod + mod) % mod;
```

In our case (`mod == 26`) we'll have (I've put `key % 26` instead of just `key` in order not to have *integer overfow* in case of *huge* `key`, e.g. `key = int.MaxValue`):

```
static char cipher(char ch, int key) {
  if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    return (char)('a' + ((ch - 'a' + key % 26) % 26 + 26) % 26);
  else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    return (char)('A' + ((ch - 'A' + key % 26) % 26 + 26) % 26);

  return ch;
}
```

Then you can put (let's use *Linq*)

```
string Encipher(string input, int key) => 
  string.Concat(input.Select(c => cipher(c, key)));

// Same as Encipher, but with negative key: note -key 
string Decipher(string input, int key) => 
  string.Concat(input.Select(c => cipher(c, -key)));
```